# Java method parameter gives compilation error "Unexpected bound"

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

Out of these 2 methods inspect1 shows compilation error "Unexpected bound" and inspect2 works fine, why ?

```
public <U> void inspect1(List<U extends Number> u){
    System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
}

public <U> void inspect2(List<? extends Number> u){
    System.out.println("T: " + t.getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("U: " + u.getClass().getName());
}
```

Comment: When you declare the generic type `U`, you allow all types because you wrote `<U>` and not `<U extends Number>`. That means, that it is completely unsafe to assume that `List<U extends Number>` would work, because `U` could be a `Car`. You want to make a restriction to the type declaration itself, so `<U extends Number>` and then just use `List<U>`.
The second snippet does not use the type `U` at all. The list declaration thus accepts every list which contains `Number` types, so a `List<Integer>` for example.

Answer (score 3):

To make it work, this should be defined in the generic type method signature saying that `U` can be any type that is a subclass of `Number`:

```
public <U extends Number> void inspect1(List<U> u) {
    // body
}
```

Also, note in the second method, the parameter `U` is never used and should be as below. This says that any list of a subclass of `Number` is accepted. No generic parameter `U` is involved.

```
public void inspect2(List<? extends Number> u) {
    // body
}
```

> Is there going to be any difference between these 2 methods (inspect1 and inspect2) you have provided in the answer, or they are going to work exactly the same?

They practically do the same since you cannot extend `Number` and the only types extending this class are (hope I got them all):

- `Double`, `Float`, `Short`, `Integer` and `Long`

Comment: I think inside inspect2 we can not insert elements in list u, that makes it different than inspect1. And somehow I kind of forgot that is feature of using upper bound wildcard. You may want to edit this in answer.

Comment: To calrify "inspect2 we can not insert elements in list u", except null.